# Display a contact using storagekind.phone

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8

I want to display a phone contact only,using storagekind.phone. because I already retrieve a contact using filterkind but, I need storagekind only. help me plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look if you want use **storageKind** you have go the **Accounts** class of **using Microsoft.Phone.UserData;** like this...

```
Account Accounttype = new Account();
StorageKind strgKind = StorageKind.Phone;

Accounttype.Kind = strgKind;
```

hope it helps you..